# How to write your original (non-Chinese) and Chinese name, jointly

Tags: writing, names

What is the most appropriate way to write both your non-Chinese, as well as your Chinese name, in one text line combined, e.g. at the bottom or top of a document.

***Clarification:*** by this, I mean that the document (e.g. a letter, a resume, or a report) is written by the person signing or 'heading' that document.

I am looking for the most appropriate answer, with regards to the *"Chinese"*-language context, disregarding that the document itself might not be Chinese.

Is it one of the following options, and if so; which one please:

"FIRST NAME" "LAST NAME" ‧ "CHINESE LAST NAME" "CHINESE FIRST NAME"

"FIRST NAME" "LAST NAME" · "CHINESE LAST NAME" "CHINESE FIRST NAME"

"FIRST NAME" "LAST NAME" • "CHINESE LAST NAME" "CHINESE FIRST NAME"

"FIRST NAME" "LAST NAME" ∙ "CHINESE LAST NAME" "CHINESE FIRST NAME"

The inter-punctuation characters used in the options above are:

**`‧` hyphenation point** (HTML-code: `&#8231;`),

**`·` interpunct** (HTML-codes: `&#183;` or `&middot;`),

**`•` bullet** (HTML-codes: `&#8226;` or `&bull;`) and

**`∙` bullet operator** (HTML-code: `&#8729;`)

respectively ... even though this Stack Exchange website doesn't seem to format the bullet operator in a very standard way/font-size.

Or is there any other punctuation which is more standardized? Perhaps even using simple brackets `()` (or is that not the *"Chinese"* way)? Or should one simply use the Chinese point: `。`?

Also: should the punctuation marks or names receive a different font-size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best source is [百度 百科](https://baike.baidu.com/) here's some examples of how they do it:

> [基努·里维斯（Keanu Reeves）](http://baike.baidu.com/link?url=A-6HKfeV8CbWIFpz5BB1BxRcUspxpDOsooajTofKb4vCMGcV-3n53g8nbTUSVsGQg-vwWkvKHhAIdndzgla1pX3gs8cUzoY8F5RjUbxyOoAl-wKRP6qVijRNkm7nSnYMkJSRhu8ewEx7pZfiUkamr8UzquVV0DoxKzjo2OpBx49AHMif3sJlGP2jUFyJLXwmPPUuwW0Kb6RyMVEqJW108q)
>
> [布兰妮·斯皮尔斯（Britney Spears）](http://baike.baidu.com/link?url=gJW3gsPlCk6z1wE2p0B4YziIYbxN5MmhoTdbA88zGapjUTHzkZ6iqsX9cpUp2vJDsUE-j706-9jnIkzLabBMFCknfzd6HZDiduBl33IfrSneGfWQtuHKoojVvL67mTKWdsgcz_An9lZnywWnDcu7D9HHoH_OKZ6v-vCXG9s3Di7)
>
> [奥兰多·布鲁姆（Orlando Bloom）](http://baike.baidu.com/link?url=kOmzPQ2sg9YVJbe5U11lFpWj93CvgOySeWi3cnxvjfThKurcerhTF0fTktgsVm0IFgzS0Hb88Bu4kE0sn2Q3szxcl-1gaiVEtc2P7rxn7-dRQmIq5HTalzuUwseIV6YAqkj9pYVgW0aK-Yfa6wFRYUmoars_G-B-BEKK_pQAgXdJWpxypmezq4XSnhOIo_RPmvyINKHbhf_iIS2NyDXnNa)

So the format here is: `transliterated first name` + `·` (interpunct code point U+00B7 · MIDDLE DOT) + `transliterated surname` + `（` (General purpose
(fullwidth East-Asian) / U+FF08 Fullwidth left parenthesis) + `）` (General purpose
(fullwidth East-Asian) / U+FF09 Fullwidth right parenthesis)

Also, you can see there is no space after the Chinese name and the left parenthesis.

Your name then would look something like this:

文森特·费尔海恩（Vincent Verheyen）

the reverse would also work for said purpose

Vincent Verheyen（文森特·费尔海恩）

---

Out of curiosity, here's also an example of a famous westerner with a Chinese name - with his Chinese name and then western-name on a "single line"

[大山（本名马克·亨利·罗斯韦尔，Mark Henry Rowswell）](http://baike.baidu.com/link?url=TOxY5jESaFfWWw5g2TtkYyKx34-hSLITHthK_lcQgg2QMCcxMa0mpOkgGSFF2MpN89OTtDIcHMq1PG30tt8HRFLQeABOcxx-Mw0AVtwBA0m)

Comment: Thanks @user3306356. I presumably hadn't specified enough that I meant that the document is being *authored* or given authority by the person in question. I had hinted at it by writing *"in one text line combined, e.g. at the bottom or top of a document"*. I have now added a **Clarification** in bold face to the OP.

Comment: Also: please note that I wrote: *"disregarding that the document itself might not be Chinese."*

Comment: This is the most Chinese-centric way to do it - that's what I assumed you were looking for - if I read it right

Comment: You have well understood it that I am asking for a Chinese-centric way, which is a cleverly-found description. However, do you think the presented format is OK to reverse, in keeping the Chinese punctuation context, but changing the order so that the original name comes before the transliterated name? This would be more appropriate if the document was not Chinese, but written in a Western language. If you could reply on that question in your answer, I would very happy to accept it. -- Also: note that your sources are **not** documents authored by the persons in question. Any discrepancies?

Comment: To clarify that last point again: I am not looking for sources in which the names are written in an afterwards (or previously) continuing sentence. What I am looking for (cf. **Clarification** in OP) is the name-*heading* at the top of a document, or the name-*signing* at the bottom of a document, without any other information on that line of text (other than the relevant names).

Comment: I get where you're coming from. I think that this is just your best bet of any sort of "precedent," if you will, - most people would either just go Chinese or English but not both - so it's hard to find any other examples. I've updated the answer to include that the reverse would also work - with your SE name as an example. Perhaps, though, someone else can give you a more **authoritative** answer than I can.

Comment: I have discussed this further with Chinese-language natives, and it appears that your answer only suffices for transliterated names. If the Chinese name is not an exact or almost exact transliteration, the middle dot should not appear, and the order of the Chinese names should be reversed.